# How can I get my older Docker image from Heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku

I built and pushed a Docker image to Heroku container registry using

```
heroku container:push worker
```

but then I noticed that my Docker image was missing some files that the previous image had. I don't have those files anymore so I want to get that older Docker image to eventually get those files.

I rolled back release version and know that the current running version has my files. However, when I use

```
docker container:pull -d worker
```

It pulls the latest pushed version, not the currently running version of my Docker image.

I have tried using `heroku ps:copy`, `heroku ps:exec`, but none of these work on Docker images, at least without modifying the image, which I don't want because modified image won't have the files I'm looking for. I specifically want the files that my current running Docker image has.